# Does taking log of a sub-exponential random variable(larger than 1) is still sub-exponential？

Tags: probability, random-variable

It feels intuitive that if a random variable x(>1) is subexponential, then log(x) should also be a subexponential random variable. But I don't know how to show it properly. Does anyone have any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vershynin](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) defines a random variable X as sub-exponential, if for all t≥0 there is a constant K>0 such that:
$$ \mathbb{P}(|X| \ge t) ≤2exp(−t/K) $$
Suppose that $X>1$  (a.s.). Since $ln(x)$ is a strictly increasing function in $(x)$ it follows that

$$ \mathbb{P}(|ln(X)| \ge t) = \mathbb{P}(ln(X) \ge t) = \mathbb{P}(X \ge e^t) = \mathbb{P}(|X| \ge e^t) \\
\le  2exp(−e^t/K) \\
$$
The proof is complete if we can show that  $-e^t \le -t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ because then
$$ \mathbb{P}(ln(X) \ge t) \le 2exp(−e^t/K) \le 2exp(−t/K) $$

This is equivalent to showing that $f(t) = -e^t - t \le 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. If we evaluate the function at $t = 0$ we find $f(0) = -1$.  Notice that $f'(t) = -e^t - 1$ and that $f''(t) = -e^t \le 0$. Notice that $f'(0) = 0$, and that the function is strictly concave. Therefore $f(t)$ achieves a unique maximum at $t = 0$ and consequently the function is always negative.

Therefore $ln(x)$ must be subexponential. This makes a lot of intuitive sense because the log function just makes everything smaller, and therefore the tails must be thinner.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ecnmetrician! I actually got to the same proof as you did. :)

Comment: Do you know of a way to show this using the fifth equvalent definition of sub-exponential instead:
The MGF of $X$ satisfies
$$
\mathbb{E} \exp (\lambda X) \leq \exp \left(K_{5}^{2} \lambda^{2}\right) \quad \text { for all } \lambda \text { such that }|\lambda| \leq \frac{1}{K_{5}}
$$
If $X-\mathbb{E}(X)$ satisfy the above definition with parameter $K_5$, what parameter would $ln(X)-\mathbb{E}(ln(X))$ satisfy this definition with?

Comment: The new $K_5^*$ would be $\sqrt{K_5^2 + \mathbb{E}(X) -  \mathbb{E}(ln(X))}$. These are the steps: First, plug in the demeaned variable in the definition with $x$. Second, multiply both sides of the inequality by $exp(\lambda  \mathbb{E}(X) -  \lambda\mathbb{E}(ln(X)))$. Third, notice that $\lambda < \lambda^2$ and see that this allows you to build the new K. You can also verify that the domain of $lambda$ with the new K is a subset of before. Finally, use the fact that $ln(x) < x$ for all $x$ to complete the left inequality, because exp is monotonic and expectations preserve inequalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ecnmetrician! I'm wondering about the step where you use $\lambda < \lambda^2$. This is true if $\lambda > 1$. How do you deal with the case of $\lambda \leq 1$?